# How to open cmd and run ipconfig in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I would like to write a script that do something like that: open the cmd and run  the commend "ipconfig"  and than copy my ip and paste it to a text file.
I wrote the beginning of the script but I didn't get the results that I wanted.
Here is the start of the script:

```
import os
f = os.system("cmd/ipconfig")
```

I got instead of getting the ipconfig output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
???(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. �� ������� ������.

C:\Users\vespper\PycharmProjects\toturial>
```

Comment: Any reason not to just run the command?? `os.system("ipconfig.exe")`. BTW the only value in `f` would be the exit value, `ipconfig.exe` will just print to `stdout`. For that you would need something like `subprocess.run`

Comment: The most immediate problem is that you're not using the correct command-line syntax for cmd.exe.  It should be `cmd /c ipconfig` though as previously mentioned there's no obvious point in using cmd.exe in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to get IP address only do like this

```
import socket
def get_ip_address():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    return s.getsockname()[0]
```

or

If you really want to execute `ipconfig` the way you are trying, do this to get output

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig" ).decode('utf-8')
print (proc)
```

Comment: Hello @naren, I tried the second code and got "    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". Also,how can I set my own name for the output file?

Comment: Hey sorry, I forgot that you are running python-3. In py3 you need to decode to utf-8.

Comment: ipconfig.exe defaults to writing OEM encoded text with CRLF line endings to a pipe. In Python 3.6+, use `output = check_output('ipconfig', encoding='oem')`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

```
import os
os.system("ifconfig")
```